# How to prevent the T function from being wrapped in the anonymous function using babel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, transpiler

I have the following javascript file to be parsed with babel:

```
b(a)
```

I have the following javascript file that I use to detect calls to functions in the previous file and replace them with a function that receives the previous function and its parameters to call it.

```
const t = require("babel-types")

module.exports = function (babel) {
    return {
        visitor: WrapperVisitor
    }
}
const WrapperVisitor = {
    Program(path) {
        path.traverse(CallVisitor)
    }
}
let cont = 0
const CallVisitor = {
    CallExpression(path) {
        if (path.node.callee.name){
            let cam = path.node.arguments.slice()
            path.node.arguments.push(t.identifier(path.node.callee.name))
            path.replaceWith(
                t.functionDeclaration(
                    t.identifier("T"),
                    path.node.arguments,
                    t.blockStatement(
                        [
                          t.expressionStatement(
                              t.callExpression(
                                  t.memberExpression(
                                      t.identifier(path.node.callee.name),
                                      t.identifier("apply")
                                  ),
                                cam
                              )
                          )
                        ]
                    )
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

This generates the following output file

```
(function () {
  function T(a, b) {
    return b.apply(a);
  }
})();
```

The question is: how to prevent the function T from being wrapped in the anonymous function and in those parentheses, and where can I find more documentation of the path object?